# PHP Handling error from a returned array

Tags: php, arrays

at the moment I do something like this

```
exec($command, $retval);
```

The response is normally an array, which has either the value success or failure.  At the moment, I am doing something like the following

```
if($retval[0] === 'success') {
    //do something else
} else {
   //handle the error
}
```

I have noticed though that sometimes, I see an error in the console which states

> Undefined offset: 0 in

I presume that sometimes something is happening and an array is not returned.  It is executing a Python script.

Is there any way I can handle if the offset is 0?  I would have presumed this would have been handled in the else clause, but apparently not.

Thanks

Comment: `if(isset($retval[0]) && $retval[0] === 'success') { do what ever you want } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the case using an [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) like so, as @Basheer Ahmed also pointed out above in a comment :

```
if( isset( $retval[0] ) && $retval[0] === 'success' ) {
    //do something else
} else {
   //handle the error
}
```